# Requesting nearest city in android

Tags: java, android, locationmanager

I need to calculate the near city in an android app using only the Network provider.
I manage to do it with the following code but it turns the app very slow and it works only sometimes.

```
public Locator(final Context c) {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) c.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(c, Locale.getDefault());
        List addresses;
        try {
            addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                if(addresses.get(0).getLocality()!=null){
                    Locator.setCity(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [Google Place API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search). Here is a [example & tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-working-with-google-places-and-maps-tutorial/)